# Serving data and web views from one Angular 7 server

Tags: angular, web-services

I'm trying to figure out how to serve both web pages and data out of the same Angular 7-based website. Various Google queries haven't led me to an answer.

Angular builds its response from the top down (unlike, say, ASP.NET, where the page corresponding to the requested URL declares the master page into which it will be embedded), with the page's outer framework defined in index.html, into which a shell defined, by default, by AppModule is embedded. So the structure of the Angular project seems to be aimed at responding to requests with one type of response: an HTML response.

So how do I structure things if I want the same website to offer, as well, a collection of HTTP services that return data in JSON format, delivered as "application/json"? How does the routing to these services work, and how does one bypass index.html and set the desired Content-type?

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET, you can create application having Angular SPA as View Type Selected.

For more info, visit:

[Post 1 -- Run in same server](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/the-best-ways-to-connect-to-the-server-using-angular-cli-b0c6b699716c)

[Post 2](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/creating-an-angular-7-app-with-aspnet-core-step-by-step-guide)

[Post 3](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-an-angular-7-app-with-asp-net-core-2-1/)

The added advantage is both the applications will run on same port and you won't face any `CORS` issue

Answer (score 0):

I think that one of this articles can help you:

[Navigating beetwen 2 app](https://medium.com/disney-streaming/combining-multiple-angular-applications-into-a-single-one-e87d530d6527)

[Two apps on nginx server](https://medium.com/@CristianSitov/delivering-multiple-angular2-apps-with-a-single-nginx-server-at-different-urls-55b42ca4c4ce)